# How to ingest a Dataset of type Table in GCP Data Fusion to be used as lookup table in the directive 'table-lookup' in Wrangler Plug-in

Tags: dataset, lookup, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to use GCP Data Fusion Wrangler Plug-in to perform some lookup operations using the table-lookup directive. This directive has an associate table to be referred by the lookup, that must be a Dataset of type table. My doubt is how to define or ingest a table in GCP Data Fusion, which could be recognized correctly by hte table-lookup directive.

Answer (score 1):

Wrangler does not currently support lookup from BigQuery tables. I've created a Jira to track this: https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-16145.
You can follow that Jira for prioritization and progress.